# Not Null - Spaces on field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query that shows me the records in Oracle that are not `null` but some of the records contain spaces such as '','   ', etc.

How can I modify the query so it will ignore empty spaces?

```
select * from table where field1 is not null
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: how many such fields are there which you want to ignore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You should use trim or replace function

e.g.

1.

```
select * from table 

where field1 is not null

and trim(field1) != ''

;
```

2.

```
select * from table

where field1 is not null

and replace(field1,' ')

;
```

p.s null is not empty data ! it is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

If you problem is empty or extra space you can do something like this..

```
select * from table where replace(field1,' ','') is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where field1 is not null and trim(field1) <> ''
```